# Aggregate $sort by $cond mongoose

Tags: node.js, sorting, mongoose, aggregate

I have `sortValue`, which is `"title-asc"`, `"title-desc"`, `"createdAt-asc"`, `"createdAt-desc"`, and split it into `sortVar` ("title", "createdAt") and `sortType` ("asc", "desc") 
 And I want to sort data by sortVar and sortType conditions 
so I wrote aggregation like this ->

```
Product.aggregate([
      ...
      {
        $sort: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $eq: [sortVar, "title"]
            },
            then: {
              $cond: {
                if: {
                  $eq: [sortType, "asc"]
                },
                then: {
                  createdAt: 1
                },
                else: {
                  createdAt: -1
                }
              }
            },
            else: {

            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $sort: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $eq: [sortVar, "createdAt"]
            },
            then: {
              $cond: {
                if: {
                  $eq: [sortType, "asc"]
                },
                then: {
                  createdAt: 1
                },
                else: {
                  createdAt: -1
                }
              }
            },
            else: {

            }
          }
        }
      }
    ])
```

and return error `$meta is the only expression supported by $sort right now`... I'm new  in mongoose.. so I can not sort with conditions.. If anyone can help me, I would be so happy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add a new field with $cond, the direction can be passed in as a variable:

```
  let direction= sortType === 'asc'?1: -1;
```

the aggregate:

```
Product.aggregate(
{
     $addFields:
           {
             finalSortingValue:
               {
                 $cond: [ {$eq: [sortVar, "title"], $title, $createdAt}, 
               }
           }

      },
      {
       $sort:{
            finalSortingValue: direction
         }  
      }
);
```

Edit:
it will have big performance hit if you have already have index on title and createdAt fields.
if it is the case, I think this should be better

```
 let direction= sortType === 'asc'?1: -1;   
 if(sortVar === 'title'){   
    Product.aggregate(
          {
           $sort:{
                title: direction
             }  
          }
    );
}else{
     Product.aggregate(
          {
           $sort:{
                createdAt: direction
             }  
          }
    );

}
```

If no index, that should be OK. limit should help in this case also.

Comment: I have a question... 
if I have hundreds of thousands of documents in the collection, will it kill a lot of performance? if so, what should i do? Do I have to give a limit before sorting? Or it has more elegant solution?